# If $f:A\longrightarrow B$ is an homeomorphism, does $f(Bd(P))=Bd(f(P))$ for all $P\subset A$?

Tags: general-topology

If $f:A\longrightarrow B$ is an homeomorphism, does $f(Bd(P))=Bd(f(P))$ for all $P\subset A$ ?

I would say yes since if $f:A\longrightarrow B$ is an homeomorphism then $f|_P:P\longrightarrow f(P)$ is still a homeomorphism and I proved previously that $f|_P:Bd(P)\longrightarrow Bd(f|_P(P))$ is a homeomorphism, and thus that $f|_P(Bd(P))=Bd(f|_P(P))$, but may be it doesn't imply that $f(Bd(P))=Bd(f(P))$ when $P\subset A$ with $P\neq A$.

Comment: You can prove this by using that a homeomorphism preserves closures, complements, and intersections, and the boundary of $P$ is the intersection of the closure of $P$ and the closure of the complement of $P$.

Comment: Essentially, boundary is defined straight away in terms of the topology, hence the definition is invariant under homeomorphisms ...

Comment: thank you for your answer. Then does my proof if wrong or it's correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I, for one, don't understand your proof.

If you start out by considering the map $f\vert_P\colon P\to f(P)$, and then the "restriction" $Bd(P)\to Bd\left(f\vert_P(P)\right)$, one can get confused about in which space you think about the boundary $Bd(P)$ of $P$.

Indeed, the boundary $Bd(P)$ in the subspace $P$ is just the empty set.

Also, the reason why I write "restriction" in quotes is that the function $f\vert_P\colon Bd(P)\to Bd(f\vert_P(P))$ may not be defined, even if you think of $Bd(P)$ as the boundary of $P$ in $A$. The reason is that $Bd(P)$ is not necessarily contained in $P$, which will be the case, whenever $P$ is not closed in $A$.

Here's what I would do: You know that $Bd(P) = \bar{P}\setminus P^{\circ}$, and you know that homeomorphisms preserve closures, set differences and interiors. Thus
$$f(Bd(P)) = f\left(\bar{P}\setminus P^{\circ}\right) = \overline{f(P)}\setminus f(P)^{\circ} = Bd\left(f(P)\right).$$